# How to convert Macro NSString into NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
#define string = @"http://rtchubs.com/Client/PhotoStreamer/SaveRating.php?RateID=%@&&Rate=%@&&Photoid=%@"
```

How can I convert the string into URL format?

Comment: Do u need to convert to NSUrl??

Comment: @EmelElias yes, i want to insert the %@ literal value into the string

Comment: why or why it has to be a macro?

Comment: @Sulthan because i want to declare it globally

Comment: @user3505490 consider using const NSString instead - there is no need for a macro in this case and it is considered to be bad style for these scenarios among many developers. The reasoning for it being considered bad style in parts founds on the fact that macros are not type safe.

Comment: @user3505490 That's not a reason to use a macro. The declaration has the same visibility as a global function or a global variable (constant).

Comment: there is no need for globals in the first place.

Comment: like @Till said, make your string a NSString and then create a NSURL from the NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define these macros

```
#define STRING @"http://rtchubs.com/Client/PhotoStreamer/SaveRating.php?RateID=%@&&Rate=%@&&Photoid=%@"
#define URL_FROM_PARAMETER(_rateId_, _rate_, _photoId_) [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:STRING, _rateId_, _rate_, _photoId_]]
```

Usage

```
id rateId = @"rateid", rate = @"rate",photoId = @"photoid";
NSURL *url = URL_FROM_PARAMETER(rateId, rate, photoId);
NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

Output :

```
http://rtchubs.com/Client/PhotoStreamer/SaveRating.php?RateID=rateid&&Rate=rate&&Photoid=photoid
```

Comment: It's a good answer but it's against my better judgement to write such things to the internet because some people could actually start using macros in this way... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider just creating a pure helper function and you don't have to be concerned with how you use the URL path to construct the correct URL all over the code base.

```
// .h
extern NSURL *TLARateURL(NSString *rateID, NSString *rate, NSString *photoID);

// .c/m
NSURL *TLARateURL(NSString *rateID, NSString *rate, NSString *photoID) {
  static NSString *format = @"http://rtchubs.com/Client/PhotoStreamer/SaveRating.php?RateID=%@&&Rate=%@&&Photoid=%@";
  return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:format, rateID, rate, photoID]];
}
```